# Jquery uploader doesn't work in mozilla firefox

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I'm using [UploadFy](http://www.uploadify.com/) for uploading files on server but it doesn't work in firefox, works fine in chrome, safari, opera and IE. Can anybody help me?

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.uploadify.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(
    function () {
        $("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
            'uploader': '/Scripts/uploader.swf',
            'cancelImg': '/Images/cancel.png',
            'buttonText': 'Select File(s)',
            'script': 'Chat/FileUpload', 
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png;*.rar;*.zip',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': true,
            'onComplete': function (event, id, fileObj, response, data) {
                response = $.parseJSON(response);
               if(response.Status != null) {
                   alert(response.Status);
               }
            }
        });
    }
);
    </script>

<div id="fileuploader"></div>
```

Error: flashVer.split is not a function
Source File: http://localhost:port/Scripts/jquery.uploadify.js

```
var flashVer=-1;if(navigator.plugins!=null&&navigator.plugins.length>0){if(navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash 2.0"]||navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"]){var swVer2=navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash 2.0"]?" 2.0":"";var flashDescription=navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"+swVer2].description;var descArray=flashDescription.split(" ");var tempArrayMajor=descArray[2].split(".");var versionMajor=tempArrayMajor[0];var versionMinor=tempArrayMajor[1];var versionRevision=descArray[3];if(versionRevision==""){versionRevision=descArray[4]}if(versionRevision[0]=="d"){versionRevision=versionRevision.substring(1)}else{if(versionRevision[0]=="r"){ersionRevision=versionRevision.substring(1);if(versionRevision.indexOf("d")>0){versionRevision=versionRevision.substring(0,versionRevision.indexOf("d"))}}}var flashVer=versionMajor+"."+versionMinor+"."+versionRevision}}else{if($.browser.msie){var version;var axo;var e;try{axo=new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7");version=axo.GetVariable("$version")}catch(e){}flashVer=version.replace("WIN ","").replace(",",".")}}flashVer=flashVer.split(".")[0];if(jQuery){(function(a){a.extend(a.fn,{fileUpload:function(b){if(flashVer>=9){a(this).each(function(){settings=a.extend({uploader:"uploader.swf",height:30,width:110,cancelImg:"cancel.png",wmode:"opaque",scriptAccess:"sameDomain",fileDataName:"Filedata",displayData:"percentage",onInit:function(){},onSelect:function(){},onCheck:function(){},onCancel:function(){},onError:function(){},onProgress:function(){},onComplete:function(){}},b);var d=location.pathname;d=d.split("/");d.pop();d=d.join("/")+"/";var f="&pagepath="+d;if(settings.buttonImg){f+="&buttonImg="+escape(settings.buttonImg)}if(settings.buttonText){f+="&buttonText="+escape(settings.buttonText)}if(settings.rollover){f+="&rollover=true"}f+="&script="+settings.script;f+="&folder="+escape(settings.folder);if(settings.scriptData){var g="";for(var c in settings.scriptData){g+="&"+c+"="+settings.scriptData[c]}f+="&scriptData="+escape(g)}f+="&btnWidth="+settings.width;f+="&btnHeight="+settings.height;f+="&wmode="+settings.wmode;if(settings.hideButton){f+="&hideButton=true"}if(settings.fileDesc){f+="&fileDesc="+settings.fileDesc+"&fileExt="+settings.fileExt}if(settings.multi){f+="&multi=true"}if(settings.auto){f+="&auto=true"}if(settings.sizeLimit){f+="&sizeLimit="+settings.sizeLimit}if(settings.simUploadLimit){f+="&simUploadLimit="+settings.simUploadLimit}if(settings.checkScript){f+="&checkScript="+settings.checkScript}if(settings.fileDataName){f+="&fileDataName="+settings.fileDataName}if(a.browser.msie){flashElement='<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="'+settings.width+'" height="'+settings.height+'" id="'+a(this).attr("id")+'Uploader" class="fileUploaderBtn"><param name="movie" value="'+settings.uploader+"?fileUploadID="+a(this).attr("id")+f+'" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="'+settings.wmode+'" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="'+settings.scriptAccess+'"><param name="swfversion" value="9.0.0.0" /></object>'}else{flashElement='<embed src="'+settings.uploader+"?fileUploadID="+a(this).attr("id")+f+'" quality="high" width="'+settings.width+'" height="'+settings.height+'" id="'+a(this).attr("id")+'Uploader" class="fileUploaderBtn" name="'+a(this).attr("id")+'Uploader" allowScriptAccess="'+settings.scriptAccess+'" wmode="'+settings.wmode+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />'}if(settings.onInit()!==false){a(this).css("display","none");if(a.browser.msie){a(this).after('<div id="'+a(this).attr("id")+'Uploader"></div>');document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id")+"Uploader").outerHTML=flashElement}else{a(this).after(flashElement)}a("#"+a(this).attr("id")+"Uploader").after('<div id="'+a(this).attr("id")+'Queue" class="fileUploadQueue"></div>')}a(this).bind("rfuSelect",{action:settings.onSelect},function(j,h,i){if(j.data.action(j,h,i)!==false){var k=Math.round(i.size/1024*100)*0.01;var l="KB";if(k>1000){k=Math.round(k*0.001*100)*0.01;l="MB"}var m=k.toString().split(".");if(m.length>1){k=m[0]+"."+m[1].substr(0,2)}else{k=m[0]}if(i.name.length>20){fileName=i.name.substr(0,20)+"..."}else{fileName=i.name}a("#"+a(this).attr("id")+"Queue").append('<div id="'+a(this).attr("id")+h+'" class="fileUploadQueueItem"><div class="cancel"><a href="javascript:$(\'#'+a(this).attr("id")+"').fileUploadCancel('"+h+'\')"><img src="'+settings.cancelImg+'" border="0" /></a></div><span class="fileName">'+fileName+" ("+k+l+')</span><span class="percentage">&nbsp;</span><div class="fileUploadProgress" style="width: 100%;"><div id="'+a(this).attr("id")+h+'ProgressBar" class="fileUploadProgressBar" style="width: 1px; height: 3px;"></div></div></div>')}});if(typeof(settings.onSelectOnce)=="function"){a(this).bind("rfuSelectOnce",settings.onSelectOnce)}a(this).bind("rfuCheckExist",{action:settings.onCheck},function(m,l,j,k,o){var i=new Object();i.folder=d+k;for(var h in j){i[h]=j[h];if(o){var n=h}}a.post(l,i,function(r){for(var p in r){if(m.data.action(m,l,j,k,o)!==false){var q=confirm("Do you want to replace the file '"+r[p]+"'?");if(!q){document.getElementById(a(m.target).attr("id")+"Uploader").cancelFileUpload(p)}}}if(o){document.getElementById(a(m.target).attr("id")+"Uploader").startFileUpload(n,true)}else{document.getElementById(a(m.target).attr("id")+"Uploader").startFileUpload(null,true)}},"json")});a(this).bind("rfuCancel",{action:settings.onCancel},function(j,h,i,k){if(j.data.action(j,h,i,k)!==false){a("#"+a(this).attr("id")+h).fadeOut(250,function(){a("#"+a(this).attr("id")+h).remove()})}});a(this).bind("rfuClearQueue",{action:settings.onClearQueue},function(){if(event.data.action()!==false){a("#"+a(this).attr("id")+"Queue").contents().fadeOut(250,function(){a("#"+a(this).attr("id")+"Queue").empty()})}});a(this).bind("rfuError",{action:settings.onError},function(k,h,j,i){if(k.data.action(k,h,j,i)!==false){a("#"+a(this).attr("id")+h+" .fileName").text(i.type+" Error - "+j.name);a("#"+a(this).attr("id")+h).css({border:"3px solid #FBCBBC","background-color":"#FDE5DD"})}});a(this).bind("rfuProgress",{action:settings.onProgress,toDisplay:settings.displayData},function(j,h,i,k){if(j.data.action(j,h,i,k)!==false){a("#"+a(this).attr("id")+h+"ProgressBar").css("width",k.percentage+"%");if(j.data.toDisplay=="percentage"){displayData=" - "+k.percentage+"%"}if(j.data.toDisplay=="speed"){displayData=" - "+k.speed+"KB/s"}if(j.data.toDisplay==null){displayData=" "}a("#"+a(this).attr("id")+h+" .percentage").text(displayData)}});a(this).bind("rfuComplete",{action:settings.onComplete},function(k,h,j,i,l){if(k.data.action(k,h,j,unescape(i),l)!==false){a("#"+a(this).attr("id")+h).fadeOut(250,function(){a("#"+a(this).attr("id")+h).remove()});a("#"+a(this).attr("id")+h+" .percentage").text(" - Completed")}});if(typeof(settings.onAllComplete)=="function"){a(this).bind("rfuAllComplete",settings.onAllComplete)}})}},fileUploadSettings:function(b,c){a(this).each(function(){document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id")+"Uploader").updateSettings(b,c)})},fileUploadStart:function(b){a(this).each(function(){document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id")+"Uploader").startFileUpload(b,false)})},fileUploadCancel:function(b){a(this).each(function(){document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id")+"Uploader").cancelFileUpload(b)})},fileUploadClearQueue:function(){a(this).each(function(){document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id")+"Uploader").clearFileUploadQueue()})}})})(jQuery)};
```

and another error

Error: $("#fileuploader").fileUpload is not a function

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(window).load(     
    function () {     
        $("#fileuploader").fileUpload({     
            'uploader': '/Scripts/uploader.swf',     
            'cancelImg': '/Images/cancel.png',     
            'buttonText': 'Select File(s)',     
            'script': 'Chat/FileUpload',      
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png;*.rar;*.zip',     
            'multi': true,     
            'auto': true,     
            'onComplete': function (event, id, fileObj, response, data) {     
                response = $.parseJSON(response);     
               if(response.Status != null) {     
                   alert(response.Status);     
               }     
            }     
        });     
    }     
);     
    </script>     

<div id="fileuploader"></div>
```

Comment: any errors in the firebug? have you considered wrapping up the code inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});` instead of `window load`

Comment: Don't you initialize uploadify with $("#fileuploader").uploadify({ })?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uploadify works only if your browser has flash player installed. check if you have one from [here](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/)